# Feynman's derivation of Bernoulli (part of it)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

[image]

[image]

OK, so what's up with the $\Delta M$ here? I don't get it. In fact, my textbook doesn't even put it in. I don't think it is a type-o because he continues on with the explanation. If anything I got it from this link (it's from the Feynman lectures) http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_40.html#Ch40-S3.

Also, why do people assume these pressures are the pressures of the fluid itself? These pressures act upon the system of fluid, and are therefore outside of it! If this is true then the traditional explanation of "it has a lower pressure because it's speed is faster" is completely invalid; the correct version should be "because there was a pressure gradient the fluid accelerated".

But if we stick to the latter explanation, how can one then explain Venturi's effect? What caused the pressure gradient in this case? I think in this case one just needs to assume conservation of energy per unit volume, and do consider the pressures of the fluid.

Some people insist on the former explanation, but if that were true, then when deriving Toricelli's law, why do they consider the outside pressures and not the pressures in the fluid?

I'm very, very confused.

Answer (score 3):

> OK, so what's up with the ΔM here?

Feynman explains it well: $\Delta M$ is mass of the fluid element considered. The derivation begins with the work-energy principle: work done by the forces acting on the element equals change of energy of that element. The work of internal forces is neglected (or is zero if the fluid is incompressible) and only work of the external forces - due to other fluid elements pushing on the element considered - is considered.

> why do people assume these pressures are the pressures of the fluid itself?

The fluid element experiences pressure forces on its boundary surfaces, either from another fluid element or from some moving rigid wall (piston...). These pressure forces are given by pressure of the fluid at the interface. The purpose of the concept of the fluid pressure is to give these forces.

Comment: M * E has the units kg*J. pAvt has the units Joules. So how can they be equal? If I understood correctly, you're saying we can say they are the pressures of the fluid itself because of boundary conditions?

Comment: E is "energy per unit mass", so the proper unit for it is J/kg. The pressure is the pressure of the liquid. There is no other pressure needed in the derivation.

Comment: Aren't p1 and p2 pressures that are outside the element of fluid being considered? And these pressures exert work on the element of fluid being considered.

Comment: $p_1, p_2$ are pressures on the opposite faces of the fluid element considered. Since the pressure is assumed continuous, it also gives accurately pressure inside the element. In the limit where dimensions of the element are decreased to zero, the surface pressure and the internal pressure of the element become the same (due to continuity).